# Prove the following set spans $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

The set is:$(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)$

Which can be represented like $a(1,1)+b(2,1)+c(2,2)=(x,y)$

The matrix representation is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&&2&&2&&x\\1&&1&&2&&y\end{bmatrix}$$
When I reduce it I get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&&0&&-2&&x-2y\\0&&1&&0&&x-y\end{bmatrix}$$

So 
$$a=x-2y-2c$$
$$b=x-y$$

But when I try to see if this system works e.g. I want to span the vector (3,1)
Using my equations I get
$$a=3-2-2c=1-2c$$
$$b=3-1=2$$
And if $c=1$
$$a(1,1)+b(2,1)+c(2,2)=-1(1,1)+2(2,1)+1(2,2)=(5,3)$$

Which isn't the vector I wanted to span.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Hint: Start by noting that $(2,2)=2(1,1)$, so that you can always take $c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)= x( (2,1)-(1,1)) + y( (2,2)-(2,1) ) = x(b-a) + y(c-b)$

$=-xb+(x-y)b +yc$. So $a,b$ and $c$ span $\mathbb R^2$